# Iterating through subplots from matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, subplot

I am creating multiple horizontal stacked bar graphs in a figure using subplots :

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(kwargs), figsize=figsize, frameon = False)
subplot = 0

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        leftCordinate = 0

        for i in range(len(value)): ##value=[10,15,20]
            axs[subplot].barh([0], value[i], left = leftCordinate, color=colors[i])
            leftCordinate +=  value[i] 

        axs[subplot].axis('off')
        subplot += 1
```

The problem is when `len(kwargs)=1` , I get below error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable
```

After research I found below 3 solutions:

1. `fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(kwargs), figsize=figsize, frameon = False, squeeze = False)`
2. `axs = axs.T.flatten()`
3. `if type(axs)!=np.ndarray : # Happens if nrows=ncols=1`

   ```
     axs = np.array([[axs]])
   ```

I have tried all but none of the solution worked for me. Is there any other solution or do i need to write a separate code for my special case `len(kwargs)=1`?

Comment: I think the simplest way would be to add the following line: ```axs = axs if isinstance(axs, np.ndarray) else np.array([axs])```

Comment: This code Worked!!

Comment: Another option is to use `axs = np.ravel(axs)`which works in the 3 cases: 1 axis, a 1D array of axes and a 2D array of axes.